# How can I check if a response has already been received for Playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

Using Java, I'm trying to wait for a response to one of the Javascript scripts I'm waiting for.

I've already discovered that I can use [waitForResponse](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response), but this leads to issues if the script has already completed loading before I reach the waitForResponse statement.

Is there a way I could wait for the script to be completed but only if it hasn't been received yet?

```
        page.waitForResponse("**/*<<Script reference>>*.js", () -> { });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is **audit all traffic**.
Here you have some example:

```java
import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserType;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright;

public class Pw {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
                BrowserType chromium = playwright.chromium();
                Browser browser = chromium.launch();
                Page page = browser.newPage();
                page.onResponse(response -> System.out.println(response.status() + " " + response.url()));
                page.navigate("https://playwright.dev/java/docs/network");
                browser.close();
            }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
200 https://playwright.dev/java/docs/network
200 https://playwright.dev/java/assets/css/styles.57a5681f.css
200 https://playwright.dev/java/js/redirection.js
200 https://playwright.dev/java/assets/js/main.bdc3f5b7.js
200 https://playwright.dev/java/assets/js/runtime~main.f37ee5cd.js
200 https://playwright.dev/java/img/playwright-logo.svg
200 https://playwright.dev/java/assets/js/04005ac5.4bff4e91.js
```

This way you **will not miss your request**.
I hope I have been able to help you.